# Why is digitalWrite(a,LOW); not working on 7 Segment LED?

Tags: c++, display, arduino-uno

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;
int c = 7;
int d = 6;
int e = 5;
int f = 2;
int g = 1;
void setup(){
pinMode(a,OUTPUT);
pinMode(b,OUTPUT);
pinMode(c,OUTPUT);
pinMode(d,OUTPUT);
pinMode(e,OUTPUT);
pinMode(f,OUTPUT);
pinMode(g,OUTPUT);
}
void loop(){
digitalWrite(a, LOW);
digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
digitalWrite(g, LOW);
digitalWrite(e, LOW);
delay(1000);
digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
digitalWrite(c, LOW);
digitalWrite(g, HIGH);
digitalWrite(e, HIGH);
}
```

I'm using a 7 segment LED. Basically I want to display numbers 1-5 with a 1 second interval, however it seems that digitalWrite LOW doesn't work. It does not stop outputting.

Comment: `loop()` has no internal delay. It starts again as soon as it finishes with current iteration. So you may see a fraction of second flash for the second set of values, before it goes back to first set of values. Add another `delay()` at the end (or at the beginning).

Comment: pin 1 is Serial TX

Answer (score 0):

When Arduino reaches the end of `loop()`, it immediately calls `loop()` again. There is no delay between the calls. Hence, the values of the first group of `digitalWrite()` will quickly override the values of the second group. You will only be able to see the first values on the display. If you want to see the second group, you should put a `delay(1000)` after it.

To display numbers 1-5 with a 1-second interval, you could write something like:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;
int c = 7;
int d = 6;
int e = 5;
int f = 2;
int g = 1;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(a, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(c, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(d, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(e, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(f, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(g, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(a, LOW);
  digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(d, LOW);
  digitalWrite(e, LOW);
  digitalWrite(f, LOW);
  digitalWrite(g, LOW);

  delay(1000);

  digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(c, LOW);
  digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(e, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(f, LOW);
  digitalWrite(g, HIGH);

  delay(1000);

  digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(e, LOW);
  digitalWrite(f, LOW);
  digitalWrite(g, HIGH);

  delay(1000);

  digitalWrite(a, LOW);
  digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(d, LOW);
  digitalWrite(e, LOW);
  digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(g, HIGH);

  delay(1000);

  digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(b, LOW);
  digitalWrite(c, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(d, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(e, LOW);
  digitalWrite(f, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(g, HIGH);

  delay(1000);
}
```

The following code is a more efficient way of doing the same thing:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;
int c = 7;
int d = 6;
int e = 5;
int f = 2;
int g = 1;

void display(bool a_val, bool b_val, bool c_val, bool d_val, bool e_val, bool f_val, bool g_val)
{
  digitalWrite(a, a_val);
  digitalWrite(b, b_val);
  digitalWrite(c, c_val);
  digitalWrite(d, d_val);
  digitalWrite(e, e_val);
  digitalWrite(f, f_val);
  digitalWrite(g, g_val);
  delay(1000);
}

void setup()
{
  pinMode(a, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(c, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(d, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(e, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(f, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(g, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  display(LOW,  HIGH, HIGH, LOW,  LOW,  LOW,  LOW);
  display(HIGH, HIGH, LOW,  HIGH, HIGH, LOW,  HIGH);
  display(HIGH, HIGH, HIGH, HIGH, LOW,  LOW,  HIGH);
  display(LOW,  HIGH, HIGH, LOW,  LOW,  HIGH, HIGH);
  display(HIGH, LOW,  HIGH, HIGH, LOW,  HIGH, HIGH);
}
```